# How can I get value from partial?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use a partial as part of my form to create a new task. The partial is a dynamic list (AJAX) of categories so user can select an appropriate category.

I need to have access to categories/category_list/@current_category variable from tasks_controller to assign selected category to a task.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @task do |form| %>  
  Category:
  <%= render :partial => 'categories/category_list', :object => Category.root_list %>  
  ... 
<% end %>
```

**tasks_controller.rb**

```
def create   
  @task = Task.new(params[:task])  
  @task.category_id = ????  
  @task.save 
  ... 
end
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**If** I understand you correctly, you want to access the value of HTML field and this field is generated dynamically, but submitted statically. That does not differ from having it done without AJAX.

Given the name of the field you can access it with `params[:name_of_field]`. You can also manually specify the name of the field to be, in your case, `task[category_id]`, in which case you can omit the line with ??? from your controller, as it will be covered by `params[:task]`.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Indeed, in case of form-embedded HTML field I would have access to :category_id. But here I would like to encapsulate category selection control into a partial. The partial is a <div> with list items (<li>) inside. The list is rebuilt once a user is selecting a category until the most sibling category is selected. Then I need to retrieve ID of the selected category from partial. Please notice the partial and the form belong to different controllers.

Comment: Whether or not it is generated by two controllers, it does not matter. It all ends up as single HTML that is submitted. If you want to pass some variable from the main action/template to the partial, use `render` with`:locals=>{:local_variable=>value}`. If you want to read the value that is selected, or react to user selecting something from a dropbox, read on unobtrusive JavaScript and form observers. I may still be missing the point, though. ;) And one more thing: when there are `<li>`s, use `<ul>` or `<ol>`, not `<div>` as their container.

Comment: Right, I can simply pass values to partial. But I need example how I can retrieve value(-s) from it.

Comment: I think that somewhat contradicts the idea of partials, which should be self-contained ;) Partials can also modify and access `@variables` available for the template they are called from, so if you declare `@foo = 3` before rendering partial, then set `@foo = 5` in partial, and display `@foo` in the template after calling partial, it will be `5`.